# Fisher's exact test on 2x4 table

Tags: r, fishers-exact-test

I am working on 4 different plants. I have the (RNA-Seq) data from sequencing. I look for two events `E1` and `E2`, say, at certain positions in their genome. Let's say `E2` is the common one and `E1` is a special event. The positions I look for are identical across all 4 (in the genome). And let's say I see that the observation I have for 1 particular `position` is:

```
    P1   P2  P3  P4
E1   0   20   0   17
E2 100   80 100  120
```

Here, `P1` through `P4` refers to plants and `E1` and `E2` refers to the events. `E2` is more common. So, my objective is to actually check if `E1` occurs more often in one or more plants than in the others. If they occur at the same proportion in all, of course it is not interesting to me.

I have 2 questions: (I have already asked [question 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13977/is-fishers-exact-test-right-for-this-problem) before but didn't get an answer)

1. *Will a fisher test be right for this problem?*

   I hypothesize (Null) that the proportion of `E1` is not different in occurrence between the 4 plants. Now, I set out to find if the proportion I have here is by any means significantly different. I use R, `fisher.test()` and I get p-value=2.5e-10. So, I reject my Null hypothesis for this case because I find strong evidence against it.
2. Sometimes, I have an observation like this,

   ```
         P1   P2  P3  P4
   E1   0   20   0  17
   E2   0   80   0 120
   ```

   then `fisher.test()` gives me a p-value of 0.147. So, I don't reject the Null   hypothesis. However, from a biological point of view, I would consider this significant. However `fisher test` answers the question I originally asked. I guess the proportion `0/0` for P1 and P3 are not useful (or not used). 
   So, my question is: *Is it possible to modify the test such that it is sensitive even if `E1` and `E2` are `0` in 1 or more plants for a particular observation?*

Having thought a bit to frame this post, I guess, in that case I have to ask a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Fisher exact test in your first example, though with so large a sample then a Chi-square test will give a similar result and without specialist software will be easier to calculate.  Just looking at the numbers, it seems obvious you will reject your null hypothesis: `E1` happens quite frequently in your observations of `P2` and `P4` but not at all with `P1` and `P3`.

In your second example you have no information at all about `P1` and `P3`.  So all you are testing is whether there is a difference between `P2` and `P4`.  There is a difference in your observations, but it is obviously not as large as in your first example.  The statistic is telling you the difference is not significant and so you should not reject your null hypothesis.  And this is what you need to be told with this data.

Comment: Henry, thanks a lot for clarifying this. My example in the first data is just an extreme one. I have a lot of other entries which aren't as obvious as this one. I of course do a multiple testing correction after this. And yes, I do a chi square test in cases where the observations are >=5. Thank you so much!